# Equivalence of boundedness definitions in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove a proposition in a set of lecture notes on metric topology. There's one particular direction in the proof of equivalence that I'm not able to follow. The proposition is:

> Let $E$  be a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$. The following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $E$, considered as a subspace of $X$, is bounded: there exists a real number $B$ such that $d(p,q) < B$ for all $p,q \in X$.
>
> (ii) There exists $p \in E$ and a real number $M$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $q \in E$.
>
> (iii) There exists $p \in X$ and a real number $M$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $q \in E$.

The proof that (i) implies (ii) is almost immediate; I need only fix any $p \in E$ and set $M = B$. The proof that (ii) implies (iii) follows by taking the same $p$ and $M$ from (ii) since $p \in E \subset X$.

The proof that (iii) implies (i) I'm having trouble figuring out. By (iii), there exists a $p \in X$ (but not necessarily in $E$) and some $M > 0$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $q \in E$. I'm struggling with proving (i), because the result in (i) has to hold for all $p,q \in X$, but (iii) only bounds the distance for all $q \in E$. The proof in the notes sets $B = 2M$, and argues that, by the triangle inequality, for any $q,q' \in E$, we have
$$
d(q,q') \leq d(q,p) + d(p,q') < B + B = 2B = M. 
$$
If $q,q' \in E$, this is fine, but one or both may be in $X - E$. I'm not sure how to treat this case: whether I can add and subtract and use the triangle inequality, or if the intended definition in (iii) was that this result held for all $q \in X$. But if that were the case, the proof that (ii) implies (iii) wouldn't be immediate.

Comment: As you have written it (i) is a statement that does not depend on $E$. It says that the ambient space $X$ is bounded.Are you sure you have transcribed the question correctly?

Comment: As @RobArthan’s question suggests, the last part of (i) should clearly say “$p,q\in E$, and that indeed resolves your problem exactly.  This is certainly transcription problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, to both of you. My mistake was in using the definition of boudedness for $X$ rather than for $E$.